# Change Div display element on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

Hi all I have a div in a project that has `display=none` until it reaches a certain scroll position then it changes to `display=block`.

This works and is great, whats not so great is the abruptness of the change. I'd like to find a way for it to ease in to view over, say, 50px.

The div I am looking to do this with has this structure

```
<div class=section id=anchoredCtaWeb>
  <div class=container>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the style and JS I have applied to it currently

```
<style>
#anchoredCtaWeb {
display: none;
position: sticky;
top: 0px;
}
</style>

<script>
document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {

if (window.pageYOffset > 817)
document.getElementById('anchoredCtaWeb').style.display = "block";

if (window.pageYOffset < 817)
document.getElementById('anchoredCtaWeb').style.display = "none";

});
</script>
```

I know the way its acting is exactly what I've written but I have been unsuccessful with transitioning the height from 0px to its full height.

I really appreciate any feedback, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by adding a `class` to `#anchoredCtaWeb` on scroll.

```js
document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  const anchoredCtaWeb = document.getElementById("anchoredCtaWeb");
  if (window.pageYOffset > 817) {
    anchoredCtaWeb.classList.add("show");
  }
  if (window.pageYOffset < 817) {
    anchoredCtaWeb.classList.remove("show");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 600vh;
}

#anchoredCtaWeb {
  position: sticky;
  transform: translateY(50px);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 10px;
}

#anchoredCtaWeb.show {
  transform: translateY(0px);
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="section" id="anchoredCtaWeb">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Check it in action on Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/yLVOMPE*

Comment: Thanks @Manas! This worked great I did add a height element to the css because with `visibility=hidden` the div was still "visible". I appreciate the quick response!

Comment: @kinzito17 yea you are right it was still "visible".